# How to set rotation for each StylusPoint in a Stroke

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to develop a calligraphy app. For this reason i'm using Windows Ink (System.Windows.Ink).
Let's say:
I have an InkCanvas (CB_Main).
To create a clligraphy pen i used the DrawingAttributes like this:

```
DrawingAttributes da = new DrawingAttributes();
da.StylusTip = StylusTip.Ellipse;
da.Width = 50;
da.Height = 2;
da.Color = Colors.Black;
da.FitToCurve = true;
Matrix m = new Matrix(); m.Rotate(280);
da.StylusTipTransform = m;
```

Then i created three StylusPoints and added them to a StylusPointCollection:

```
StylusPoint newStylusPoint = new StylusPoint(200, 200);
StylusPoint newStylusPoint2 = new StylusPoint(500, 250);
StylusPoint newStylusPoint3 = new StylusPoint(800, 200);
StylusPointCollection spc = new StylusPointCollection(spd);
spc.Add(newStylusPoint);
spc.Add(newStylusPoint2);
spc.Add(newStylusPoint3);
```

Created a Stroke from the StylusPointCollection using the information provided by the DrawingAttributes (da) declared above, And added it to my InkCanvas:

```
CB_Main.Strokes.Add(new Stroke(spc));
```

Everything is fine; but this aproach makes the StylusTip rotation the same for every single StylusPoint in the Stroke.
What i really want is to set a different "Rotation" for each StylusPoint (programmatically) because this is the real calligraphy pen behavior.
I tried to use **StylusPointDescription**; but without success
Any idea?..